# DCT Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have a random random variable with finite mean $X$, and sequence of events such that $P(A_n)\to 0$. Now $X\mathbf{1}_{|X|>n}\le |X|$ for all $n$ and so we by DCT we get that $E(X\mathbf{1}_{|X|>n})\to 0$. Then it is easy to see that
$$ E(X\mathbf{1}_{A_n})\le E(X\mathbf{1}_{A_n}\mathbf{1}_{|X|>n})+E(X\mathbf{1}_{A_n}\mathbf{1}_{|X|\le n})\to 0. $$

However notice that $\infty> E|X|\ge \sum_n P(|X|>n)$ and so $\sum_n P(|X|>n)P(A_n)$ should  converge as well (here this index $n$ really should be a subsequence) Any way, the Borel-Cantelli lemma should be applicable here and I am wondering if there was an alternative way to prove this result without the integration results.

Comment: What DCT means ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Short for "dominated convergence theorem".

Comment: @saz I wondered what Discrete Cosine Transform (with very common acrony DCT) was doing there...

Comment: Yes sorry, DCT is almost always Dominated convergence theorem when working with statistics :)